# Hive subquery in where clause (Select * from table 1 where dt > (Select max(dt) from table2) )..please suggest an alternative

Tags: hive, hiveql, apache-hive

I am looking for something in hive like

```
Select * from table 1 where dt > (Select max(dt) from table2)
```

Obviously hive doesn't support sub queries in where clause and also, even if I use joins or semi join, it compares only = and not > (As far as I know).

Can some one please suggest me an alternative solution to write the same query in hive?

Answer (score 8):

```
select table_1.* from table_1
join (select max(dt) as max_dt from table2) t2
where table_1.dt > t2.max_dt
```

You're right, you can only have equality conditions in the join `on` clause, but you can have whatever you want in the `where` clause.

Usually this isn't recommended, since not having an `on` clause means Hive will first do a full cartesian product, then filter, but since one side of the join only has one row, that's not an issue here.